# What mean JAX-RPC-based web service endpoints (in context of EJB)?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-6

I read *Beginning Java EE 6 platform with GlassFish 3* from Antonio Goncalves. 
In chapter about EJBs he wrote that some features of EJB may be deprecated in next releases of Java EE.

> > None of the following features is actually removed from EJB 3.1, but
> >     the next version will have to either remove or retain some of them:
>
> - JAX-RPC-based web service endpoints

But I not understand what he mean here. He wrote about classes annotated with `@Stateless` and `@WebService`? i.e.

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class MyService { 

}
```

So it is bad practice to annotate one class with this both annotations? It is better to separate classes? Create one to act  only as EJB, and create another class to act only as as WebService (which delegates method invocation to EJB defined as class-member)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `@Stateless` and `@WebService` are not part of JAX-RPC. They belong to EJB3 and JAX-WS. They will not be deprecated.

[JAX-RPC 2.0 was renamed JAX-WS 2.0](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohlert/archive/2005/05/jaxrpc_20_renam.html) in 2005.

Comment: ok, thank you, I understand. But what about annotating 2 classes with both annotations - `@Stateless` and `@WebService`? It is bad practice?

Comment: No, that's totally normal practice. But talking about EJB annoations would be a different topic.